# Hyperledger fabric difference between Attribute based Access Control vs Policy

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, abac, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I am reading the HLF document,In document they have policy for channel and chain-code. HLF also have Access control list and Attribute based Access Control. What is major difference and when and where Attribute based Access Control will be used and how to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hyperledger fabric is permission based blockchain. So to achieve permissions fabric provide support for permission at network config level (Policies)as well as chaincode level(ABAC or Private Data).
first of all I will explain network config level:

```
Form Docs:policy is a set of rules that define the structure for how decisions are made and 
specific outcomes are reached. To that end, policies typically describe a who and 
a what, such as the access or rights that an individual has over an asset. We can 
see that policies are used throughout our daily lives to protect assets of value 
to us, from car rentals, health, our homes, and many more.
```

Policies are defined in confgtx.yaml file as follows:

```
 Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Writers:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.client')"
        Admins:
            Type: Signature
            Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
```

Organization , channel , orderer and application component has their own policies.

Foe more explination : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/master/policies/policies.html

you can also check out first-network from fabric samples where they have used policies in configtx.yaml file so you can understand it easily.

Attribute Based Access Control(ABAC):
ABAC is used where developer wants to implement access restriction at chaincode level. for example if some asset is only allow to those users, they have attribute agent. then you can use ABAC.
ABAC is very related with fabric-ca because attributes are defined in ca certificates. the huperledger fabric run time extract attribute from user request proposal and provide it to chaincode  then chaincode validate it.
to use it you have to import CID(Client Identity) library in your chaincode file.(Note: keep in mide you to download CID lib if not found, keep vendor dir within chaincode dir)

Link to CID Docs:https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid

Link to github page:https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/core/chaincode/lib/cid/README.md